# What is that book with many gods and as many schools of magic, with the god of fire supposedly the greatest, and which features tempest?

Tags: story-identification, novel

What is that book with many gods and as many schools of magic, with the god of fire supposedly the greatest, and which features tempests?

- There are many gods, each associated with an element, (fire, water, shadow, etc.), but the dominant church pretends there is only a god of fire (and they are all fire magicians).
- There are clandestine schools of magics which teach the other elements.
- The main character is part water elemental
- There are frequent tempests on this world
- It is an "archipel" world (I think, not sure about that one)
- At some point, the boy and the girl harness a Tempest Power through a combination of water, air and shadow magic
- At some point, the girl rejects all gods, and does fire magic, and proves there is no limit to what one may do with magic (not limited to one or two elements as previously thought)
- One of the characters have some kind of dolphin jewelry with associated water magic

That's all I remember, any ideas?

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? What language / country?

Comment: I'm awfully tempted to say Avatar, but I think I can restrain myself.

Comment: It sounds **vaguely** similar to the *Earthsea* series, particularly *Tombs of Atuan*.